# Override TestRun Parameters with value including semi colons in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My runsettings file contains few connectionstrings which I want to be able to override in VSTS depending on the environment.

I don't want a specific runsettings file for each environment, but I want to use *environment variables* in order to be consistent on how our other deployment release are configured.

However I'm facing issue when I want to forward to my unit test a connectionstring (or any parameter) which include a semicolon (;). It's being truncated. I've tested transmitting other value without ";" successfully.

[image: environment variables]

[image: task configuration]

settings.runsettings

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RunSettings>
          <TestRunParameters>
           <Parameter name="CRM_CONNECTIONSTRING" value="Url = https://MYCRM.crm4.dynamics.com; Username=login@email.com; Password=mypassword;" />
          <TestRunParameters>        
         </RunSettings>
```

However, when exectuting (and displaying the actual value received in the unit test) the value is truncated after the first ";"

[image]

is there a way to protect the value ?

Comment: Have using a connection string successfully on VSTS - Visual Studio Test version 2.139.9. No workaround required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ending up to answer to myself with a workaround after contacting microsoft directly.

issue come up as well here on official vsts-task github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2567

Workaround: before the test assembly task, run a powershell script taking path to runsettings file as parameter, reading VSTS environment variables and replace direcly XML values in runsettings.

I've provided my powershell script here : https://github.com/camous/vsts-powershell/blob/master/Set-RunSettings.ps1 
(parameters have to be prefixed by "__")

and I wrote a more complete "how to" here: https://stuffandtacos.azurewebsites.net/2016/09/28/override-runsettings-parameters-in-visual-studio-team-service-when-value-contains-semi-colons/

Answer (score 4):

Adding following (within double quotes) in Override test run parameters will also preserve the required format.

-key "$(PipelineVariableName)" instead of -key $(PipelineVariableName)

Note: I tested the above with pipeline variable value containing -(hyphen) and ' '(space).